# ASP.NET set display attributes for loading gif in ServerClick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a page with two buttons that call functions to export data in Excel and PDF format.
I would like to display a loading gif during the creation of the file and the download. 
This is the div where I put the loading gif:

```
<div id="over" style="display:none;" runat="server" clientidmode="static">
  <img style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" id="imgLoader" src="img/loader-128x/Preloader_2.gif" runat="server" clientidmode="static"/>

</div>
```

These are the buttons calling my export functions:

```
<p class="text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg red-mint btn-outline sbold uppercase" id="esportaPDF" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" onserverclick="esportaPDF_ServerClick">PDF</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg green-haze btn-outline sbold uppercase" id="esportaEXCEL" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" onserverclick="esportaEXCEL_ServerClick">EXCEL</button>                                                               
</p>
```

And, for example, this is one of my export methods, that generates a PDF file:

```
protected void esportaPDF_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BLL_Utility utilityBLL = new BLL_Utility();
        BLL_MailExport mailExportBLL = new BLL_MailExport();
        int id_hotel = Convert.ToInt32(utilityBLL.getIdHotel());
        List<ODM_MailExport> mailsExport = mailExportBLL.get(id_hotel);
        GridView GridView1 = new GridView();

        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

        GridView1.DataSource = mailsExport;

        GridView1.DataBind();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",

            "attachment;filename=emailAddress" + id_hotel + ".pdf");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();

        htmlparser.Parse(sr);

        pdfDoc.Close();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    }
```

I tried in my method, to change the style attirbute of the div, putting `over.Attributes["style"] = "display: block";` in the start, and `over.Attributes["style"] = "display: none";` after the `Response.End()`, but with no effects on the div's style

Comment: check your image path? code  over.Attributes["style"] = "display: block"; is right.

Comment: The path is right, the style change has no effect, if I check on Chrome console, but even after the row that changes the style in `over.Attributes["style"] = "display: block";` the div's style is always display: none

Comment: Can't you do this with JavaScript on the client side? It'll be much easier.